# How to append nested lists with same string together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list that looks like the following:

```
list = [['bob', '12'], ['jim', '14'], ['bob', '13']]
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
list = [['bob', '12', '13'], ['jim', '14']]
```

Is there any way this can be achieved. I can only truncate the nested lit to remove the values, but not add them into another list. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. I have tried the following:

```
i = 0
while i < len(list):
  find = list[i][0]
  for a, b in list:
    if find == a:
      list[i]].append(b)
i += 1
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: is it always a pair?

Comment: couple of notes to consider: **1:** You are overshadowing the keyword `list`. Call it something else, like `my_list`. **2:** If possible switch to using a dict of list items, like `{"bob": [12, 13], "jim": [14]}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a temporary dictionary as you combine lists:

```
tmp = {}
for name, num in lst:
    if name in tmp:
        tmp[name].append(num)
    else:
        tmp[name] = [name, num]
out = list(tmp.values())
```

Output:

```
[['bob', '12', '13'], ['jim', '14']]
```

As a side note, when you use `list` as a variable name, you can’t use `list()` constructor afterwards as the variable name shadows it. So it’s better to name your variable something else. I named it `lst` here.

Answer (score -1):

A dirty one liner :-D

```
[[k,*v] for k,v in {_ld:[_l[1] for _l in l if _l[0]==_ld] for _ld in {_l[0] for _l in l }}.items()]
```